# How to select a dropdownlist Item and show matching items in a listbox MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have two data entity models gamegenre and gamename which of course are hooked up to my table at the moment my dropdownlist is being populated with all the genres and my listbox is being populated with all the ganes. However, I dont want all the games to show (I only want to show the specific games of the genre I select from the dropdownlist) in my gamelist table there is a foreign key for a genreID in the gamegenre box. So basically If I select action from dropdown I want the listbox to be populated with all action games (at the moment it shows all games).

any suggestions?

controller:

```
private dataEntities dbGame = new dataEntities();

[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult Index()
{
    dbgenre dbgenre = new dbgenre();
    gamename gamename = new gamename();

    List<SelectListItem> dropdownItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
         List<SelectListItem> listboxitems= new List<SelectListItem>();


    foreach (dbgenre dbgenre in dbGame.dbgenre)
    {
        SelectListItem genreList = new SelectListItem();
        {
            genreList.Text = dbgenre.GameTitle;
            genreList.Value = dbgenre.GameId;
        };

        dbgenre.GameTitle = genreList.Text;
        dbgenre.Value = genreList.Value;


        dropdownItems.Add(genreList);
    }



 foreach (gamename gamename in db.gamename)
        {
            SelectListItem gamelist = new SelectListItem();
            {
                gamelist.Text = gamename.Username;
                gamelist.Value = gamename.UserId.ToString();
            }

            gamename.Username = gamelist.Text;
            gamename.UserId = Int32.Parse(gamelist.Value);

            ViewBag.sitems = sourceItems;
            listboxItems.Add(gamelist);

        }


     GameViewModel gameModel = new GameViewModel();

         gameModel.dropdown = dropdownItems;
         gameModel.listbox = listboxitems;

    return View(dbdata);

}
```

viewModel:

```
public class GameViewModel
{


    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dropdown { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listbox { get; set; } 

}
```

view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.dropdown, Model.dropdown)
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => Model.listbox, Model.listbox)
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?